# Mixed modelling with lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I've read multiple posts on model fitting using `lmer()`, but I saw multiple versions of using the error term which made it confusing for me. I have a factorial design with 2×2×2 with one between and two within factors. I do an eyetracking task in which participants are in one of two sound conditions (`cond`). Each participant does the same task in which they see/don't see prime pictures (`cat`). I estimate whether people look more at matching vs. non-matching targets (`means_side`).

My basic model is (`cat`= prime vs. control):

```
fm1 <- lmer(Attention ~ cond*cat*means_side + (1|pp) , data)
```

Since I saw a lot of variation in the different category pictures I used (four different prime pictures and a control picture, coded as `category`) I want to allow this variable to vary in my model, so I used:

```
fm2 <- lmer(Attention ~ cond*cat*means_side + (1|pp) + (1|category) , data)
```

OR

```
fm3 <- lmer(Attention ~ cond*cat*means_side + (1|pp) + (category|cat) , data)
```

I am not sure which one to choose, or whether I simply have to use category instead of `cat` in the model specifications.
Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Define pp please.

Comment: Ah apologies, that would be participant (or subject)

Answer (score 0):

The model

```
fm3 <- lmer(Attention ~ cond*cat*means_side + (1|pp) + (category|cat) , data)
```

looks strange to me, for two reasons

1. Your cluster-ID variable `cat` is also an explanatory variable.
2. The random effects variable `category` is not an explanatory variable.

Finally `(category|cat)` means *the effect of `category` is different across different groups of `cat`.* Without modeling the effect of `category`(see point 2), this is a bit odd.